# How to avoid indirect dependencies in go.mod file

Tags: go

I am running `go build` to get my `go.mod` file updated with library I am using "github.com/gocolly/colly v1.2.0" But I see all other dependencies saying "// indirect" at end. 
How to avoid getting this?
Here is my go.mod file

```
   module prodenv

go 1.13

require (
   github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.5.1 // indirect
   github.com/antchfx/htmlquery v1.2.2 // indirect
   github.com/antchfx/xmlquery v1.2.3 // indirect
   github.com/antchfx/xpath v1.1.5 // indirect
   github.com/gobwas/glob v0.2.3 // indirect
   github.com/gocolly/colly v1.2.0
   github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20200121045136-8c9f03a8e57e // indirect
   github.com/kennygrant/sanitize v1.2.4 // indirect
   github.com/saintfish/chardet v0.0.0-20120816061221-3af4cd4741ca // indirect
   github.com/temoto/robotstxt v1.1.1 // indirect
   golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200324143707-d3edc9973b7e // indirect
   google.golang.org/appengine v1.6.5 // indirect
)
```

Comment: These _are_ (indirect) dependencies and you cannot "avoid" them except not using the (direct) dependency which uses them.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't avoid them. Indirect dependency, is basically dependency that wasn't listed in `go.mod` of your direct dependency, but is still required by it.

In your case it happens, because you use `github.com/gocolly/colly v1.2.0` as dependency and `v1.2.0` of this package isn't a module, because it doesn't contain `go.mod`, so all it's dependencies are indirect and listed in your `go.mod` with `indirect` tag.

Note, that `colly` has `go.mod` in >=[v2.0.0](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/blob/master/go.mod), so if you require that version, these dependencies won't be listed as indirect in your `go.mod`.

Comment: Why is this "unfortunate"?

Comment: @Flimzy IMO, first, they introduce messiness into dependency list of module. Second, their actually can spoil few things for you, for example `go mod graph` shows indirect dependencies as main module's dependendencies -- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27309. All that said, i don't imply that concept of "indirect" dependencies is bad. Probably i should fix it to "Unfortunately, there's packages that introduce indirect dependencies, and, sometimes you can't avoid them")

Comment: This is a really good answer. I google this and all I can find is "these are indrect dependencies, it's intentional" and that doesn't help me, because I often see `// indirect` after the only dependency I add to a fresh project, which made no sense to me. Now I know that it's when your dependency isn't a Go module.

Comment: Is there a way to identify to which dependency the indirect ones belong?

Comment: @stefan You can use `go mod graph` and try to visualize output with [modgraphviz](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/cmd/modgraphviz). Maybe there's better way, but i'm unaware about it.

Comment: @stefan `go mod why` answer that, now

Comment: This is annoying behavior. `go mod tidy` installs `//indirect` packages which are used within an *example* folder that the repository provides.

Answer (score 10):

`go mod tidy` helped me remove the indirect from go mod for me.

`go mod tidy` ensures that the go. mod file matches the source code in the module. It adds any missing module requirements necessary to build the current module's packages and dependencies, if there are some not used dependencies go mod tidy will remove those from go.

**Note : Indirect Dependencies required by the application/packages will not be removed or moved to direct dependencies. Those dependencies will still be there as indirect dependencies.**

Comment: There are two direct dependencies which are using the same indirect dependency. One of them does not have that indirect dependency listed in go.mod and the other has it listed. go mod tidy cleans up that indirect dependency. And go run fails.

Answer (score 3):

There is an update since the answer was accepted. https://go.dev/ref/mod

> At go 1.17 and above, the go command adds an indirect requirement for each module that provides any package imported (even indirectly) by a package or test in the main module or passed as an argument to go get.

Therefore, all dependencies are listed. This allows performance improvements in go tools.